# Jest encountered an unexpected token. This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new in jest and testing. Can't solve this bug for several days.

Have you ever seen this bug?

Use: create-react-app
[jest.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twtaC.png)

Jest encountered an unexpected token.

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/a.kyzmenko/Desktop/timego-platform-front/node_modules/react-timezone-select/dist/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from "react";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  2 | import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
  3 | // Packages
> 4 | import Timezone, { ITimezoneOption } from 'react-timezone-select';
    | ^
```